# Select "the best result" from subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE col1 = ANY (
    SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM table2
    WHERE first = 'blah'
    OR second = 'blahblah'
    OR third = 'blahblahblah' );
```

The subquery checks three columns (`first`, `second`, `third`). In this example I'm using `ANY`, but instead I want it to return like this:

```
If found `first` return `first`
else if found `second` return `second`
else if found `third` return `third`
```

Know what I'm saying? I can only select 1 row (the best) in priority `first`, `second`, `third`

Comment: What do you want the results to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE col1 = (
    SELECT col2 FROM table2
    WHERE first = 'blah'
    OR second = 'blahblah'
    OR third = 'blahblahblah'
    ORDER BY
    first = 'blah' DESC,
    second = 'blahblah' DESC,
    third = 'blahblahblah' DESC
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT t.*, 'first'
FROM table1 t
WHERE col1 IN (SELECT col2 FROM table2 WHERE first = 'blah')
UNION ALL
SELECT t.*, 'second'
FROM table1 t
WHERE col1 IN (SELECT col2 FROM table2 WHERE first <> 'blah' AND second = 'blahblah')
UNION ALL
SELECT t.*, 'third'
FROM table1 t
WHERE col1 IN (SELECT col2 FROM table2 WHERE first <> 'blah' AND second <> 'blahblah' AND third = 'blahblahblah' );
```

For each match (based on `col1`) it returns the first of the three conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
SELECT *, COALESCE(first, second, third) as best FROM tab
```